# Python module not found when launched in cron

Tags: 18.04, scripts, python, cron

I am running a little ubuntu server (version 18.04)

Before upgrading to 18.04 the cron was executing just fine.

This is my crontab (`sudo crontab -e`) :

```
*/5  *    * * *  PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3 /home/louis/backup-server/main.py >> /var/log/MYbackup.log 2>&1
```

But when the cron start the following is logged :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/louis/backup-server/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import config.config as config
  File "/home/louis/python_helpers/config/config.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

however if I run `sudo python3 /home/louis/backup-server/main.py` the script is correctly executed

I did run `sudo pip install python-dotenv`

Content of scripts :

```
# /home/louis/backup-server/main.py
# permissions : -rwxr-xr-x
import os
import requests
import json
import datetime
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/louis/python_helpers')
import config.config as config
import mail
import utils

def main():
    # some code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

--

```
# /home/louis/python_helpers/config/config.py
# permissions : -rwxr-xr-x 
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
# some config var
```

I do have an `__init__.py` file in `/home/louis/python_helpers/config`, let me know if for any other information I should add.

What bug me the most is that the scripts run just fine if started manually but not as cron.

Edit : I was unsure whether this question belongs here or on stackoverflow, so please tell me if I should move it (even though I don't know how beside creating a new question)

Comment: Have you ever put this command in a script and called it by crontab, instead?

Comment: My apologies but I don't get what you're asking.  What do you mean by "this command" ? Like I should create a .sh file running something like `python3 script.py` and calling this file in the cron ?

Comment: Exactly, it may work better, as Cron has affinity with bash commands

Comment: Just tried, got the same error :(
But thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the issue was pretty dumb, I did run `pip install python-dotenv` and `sudo pip install python-dotenv` (the script need root permission to access some folder) but I didn't do `sudo -H pip install python-dotenv`.

After running this command, the cron execute just fine.

Comment: same here. `pip3 uninstall <packages>` followed by `sudo -H pip3 install <packages>` got the cronjob running fine for me. But I'm wondering now if I should try virtual environment to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: pip3 uninstall <package> && sudo -H pip3 install <package> saved my life, but why?  What is -H?  --set-home?  Why does that fix this issue?  Thanks btw Faros and Nikhil.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues today, and here is how I solved it! Hope it'll help you.

Do you have two different python? Try to run:

```
where python3
```

If you have both `/usr/local/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3` there, and your package is installed in `/usr/local/lib` but you're specifying to use `/usr/bin/python3` in PYTHONPATH, it'll throw ModuleNotFoundError.

You can either:

1. specify `/usr/local/bin/python3` in your PYTHONPATH
2. or run `/usr/local/bin/python3 FILE` in your cronjob.
3. or put `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` in the first line of your file

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably this part:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3
```

because PYTHONPATH should point to where your libraries are. What happens if you remove that part of the crontab?

Comment: Well, at first I didn't have this part, but trying to figure things out I added it. However the result is exactly the same with or without that. I'll remove tho since it doesn't seems to be any helpfull

Comment: Just removed this part to be sure and the issue is still the same. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Your cron should be
*/5  *    * * *  /usr/bin/env python3 /home/louis/backup-server/main.py >> /var/log/MYbackup.log 2>&1

after /usr/bin/env give a space and mention python version

Answer (score -1):

for every user which you use for cron jobs, you should do  `pip install your-library`. Because cron uses the environment whose user run the job.